# Javascript - Highchart - tooltip position of data points and flags

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highchart, tooltip position of each data point

```
    tooltip: {
        positioner: function () {
            return { x: 80, y: 50 };
        }
    },
```

The problem is that the above option also changes the tooltip position of the flags.

How do I change the options so that the tooltip of the data point is fixed as the above option, but the tooltip position of flags remain as before?

Comment: can you create a live demo in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1:**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QcR4k/

And code:

```
            positioner: function (w,h,p) {
                var points = this.chart.hoverPoints;

                //hover points contains only standard points, not flags

                if(points) {
                    return { x: 320, y: 50 };
                } else {
                    return { x: 80, y: 50 };
                }
            }
```

As you can see, flags are not part of hoverPoints, so you can that way determine where to display tooltip.

**Solution #2:**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QcR4k/1/

Code:

```
            formatter: function() {
                var series = this.series || this.points[0].series; //shared or non-shared tooltip

              if(series.userOptions.isFlag){
                  series.chart.tooltip.isFlag = true;
                  return 'flag';
              } else {
                  series.chart.tooltip.isFlag = false;
                  return this.y + '<br> non-flag';
              }
            },
            positioner: function (w,h,p) {                    

                if(!this.chart.tooltip.isFlag) {
                    return { x: 320, y: 50 };
                } else {
                    return { x: p.plotX, y: p.plotY };
                }
            }
```

That solution uses `tooltip.formatter` to set flag, where point should be displayed - first formatter is returned, then we can manage position accordingly.

Comment: OK. I tried and it does work, but not well. Basically, each time I hover over the flag, I think it sometimes considers that I'm hovering over a data point, so the flag's tooltip still appears in a different position. But if I keep moving my mouse around, the position does change.

Also, how do I make the flag's tooltips appear at its default position? I tried " return {x:p.plotX, y:p.plotY}, but it seems to be slightly off.

Comment: My solution checks if you hover any of points (so marker will show up) and according to this will display tooltip in different places. There is another, more difficult solution for that, see updated answer. Regarding, `p.plotX` and `p.plotY` - Highcharts have more complicated positioning for a tooltip, than only returning point position. For more information, see.. sources ;)